# Pansharpened Raster Color Changes After Clipping

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, color

I have a mosaic raster of an agricultural area. In the mosaic raster, a specific agricultural field (field no. 5) looks just like this [image]

When I clip the raster with the field's shapefile (shapefile of the field no. 5) the color changes a bit and looks like the following image. [image]

The following codes have been used to clip the mosaic raster -

```
#clipping the raster
arcpy.Clip_management(in_raster= mosaic_pan_layer, rectangle=str(extent_of_shape_file), 
out_raster=pan_save, in_template_dataset=shape_file, nodata_value="65536", 
clipping_geometry="ClippingGeometry", maintain_clipping_extent="NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")


#saving the clipped raster
arcpy.CopyRaster_management (in_raster = pan_save, out_rasterdataset = Clipped_pan_save, 
nodata_value = "9999")
```

Is there any way to get the clipped raster to look exactly the same as the mosaic layer?

Answer (score 2):

this is a display issue.

The colours you see are the result of an automatic contrast enhancement of ArcGIS. When you clip the image, the statistics (min, miax, mean and STD of each spectral band) of the image change, so the contrast enhancement also changes.

If you wan the same colour, you can export as an xml the statistics of the first image, and apply them (with the same enhancement method) on the second image.

In practice, right click on the first image > properties > symbology, at the bottom you can save the statistics (if stats are not available, compute them in raster properties tools (or use "from current display extent"). Then go to the symbology of the second image. Select again "rgb composite", then "custom" type, statistics "from custom settings",  and load your xml.

[image: print screen of symbology options]

Comment: I did what you have shown. Here is the screenshot - https://prntscr.com/jy4upc
But. still having the same issue - https://prntscr.com/jy4uyk
The mosaic image has some black portion where the pixel values are 0 - https://prntscr.com/jy4up8